# SQLBase: is there a lpad function?

Tags: opentext, guptateamdeveloper, sqlbase, centura, lpad

I am using SQLBase and I have to complete a column with zeros.

This example works in PostgreSQL. I need to do the same in SQLBase but there isn't a function like `lpad`.

```
SELECT lpad(last_name, 10, '0')
FROM persons;
```

If `last_name` is *Douglas*, the result is:

```
000Douglas
```

Is there a way to define a function that can do the same as lpad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select @REPEAT('0', 10 - @LENGTH(Last_Name)  ) || Last_Name